# CLION does not find math.h anymore

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Today I upgraded CLION to version 2021.1.3

Suddenly my project turns red, because math.h ( It is a legacy project, don't ask!!!) is no longer found and even the good old printf is no longer known.

I am using the VS14 toolchain and managed to find a version of math.h that works.

My temporary super ugly fix is to specify this directory in the CMakeLists.txt but that was not necessary before and I want it gone again.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does it compile without that extra directory? Did you change your compiler between IDE versions?

Comment: No, it does not compile without it. And I did not change the project. I updated CLION and then it stopped compiling.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache both the cmake cache and the IDE cache?

Comment: Invalidating the caches and restarting did indeed do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

"Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

OK, so invalidating the caches and restarting CLION was the solution.

Thanks for the prompt replies!